# Automapper inheritance mapping factory

Tags: automapper

I have the following classes:

```
public class A{}
public class AA : A {public int aa{get;set;}}
public class AAA : A {public int aaa{get;set;}}
public class B{}
public class BB : B {public int bb{get;set;}}
public class BBB : B {public int bbb{get;set;}}
```

and this is my mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A,B>().include<AA,BB>().include<AAA,BBB>();
Mapper.CreateMap<AA,BB>();
Mapper.CreateMap<AAA,BBB>();
```

I was under the assumption that automapper will understand the hiearchy and map the appropriate derived class. But i wasn't able to get it with the codes below. The mapped entities are always the base class, in this case - B.
Please note I have a Repository factory which will determine the return type of `GetAll()`.

```
var list = myRepo.GetAll() //this returns IEnumerabe<AA> or IEnumerable<AAA> 
var newlist = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<B>>(list); //I wanted to use "B" here due to the fact I will have many inherited classes of B. I don't want to restrict to a specific child class of B.
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just a yes/no question. You'll have to verify the answer anyway, so you better try right away without asking.

Comment: Ok. Let me rephrase the question then because i couldnt get the results i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The codes above should work. Unfortunately, I was using automapper 4.1.1 and there was a bug -https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/819.